# Make entries appear in a new line when appending to a JSON file

Tags: python, json, file-io

I have been dealing with a little problem while programming python database. If I make new entry it will stay in the line with previous and I dont know where should I add \n or how could I make it in second line.
Thanks for help.
These are lines we are dealing with.
#edit: using import json
I am new to asking on stackoverflow, I dont think there are more data needed but if I made mistake I will place rest of code

```
def write_to_file(data):
    with open('database.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)

def read_from_file():
    with open('database.txt', 'r') as infile:
        return json.load(infile)

def add_entry(first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth):
    data = read_from_file()
    data.append({'id': first , 'titul': second, 'meno': third, 'priezvisko': fourth, 'ulica a cislo': fifth, 'mesto': sixth, 'psc': seventh, 'tlc': eighth, 'email': ninth})
    write_to_file(data)
```

I tried adding \n to nearly every part of the code but nothing helped

Comment: Sorry I am kinda new to this here is rest:    def write_to_file(data):
    with open('database.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)

def read_from_file():
    with open('database.txt', 'r') as infile:
        return json.load(infile)

Comment: You mean you are implementing a SQL db from scratch?

Comment: I updated it sorry

Comment: @Gameplay the term "database" also has a much broader, more informal meaning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "If I make new entry it will stay in the line with previous and I dont know where should I add \n or how could I make it in second line." I'm not sure I understand the question. **Why is this a problem**? When you tried the code, you were *able to load* the data again correctly, after saving it, right? So why does it matter what the file looks like? That said, given that the goal is to make the file look a certain way, this is a common question that has an extremely well established Q&A (the linked duplicate has more than 2 million views).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace (i.e., spaces, lines, tabs etc) doesn't matter in the JSON format. So, for compactness, the JSON module dumps to the file as one condensed chunk of text. This is a feature for many applications (like web services) where transmitting/storing a lower amount of data is valuable.

You could specify something like `indent=4` to better format the text.

```py
def write_to_file(data):
    with open('database.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```